I/flutter (15547): Exception: PlatformException(sign_in_failed, com.google.android.gms.common.api.ApiException: 10: , null, null)
I'm trying to make an android app using firebase and flutter. While doing Google SignIn, I'm confronted with this error:
I/flutter (15547): Exception: PlatformException(sign_in_failed, com.google.android.gms.common.api.ApiException: 10: , null, null)
Ive done virtually everything: my SHA keys match, I've made new firebase projects. This all started happening when i upgraded my flutter version. So i downgraded and now I'm having issues with my gradle. Any help will be appreciated, this is a super important project
Ive tried changing my SHA key, doing different projects. There may be an issue with my build.gradle files maybe?
Here they are for context:
android level:

allprojects {
repositories {
google()
mavenCentral()
}
}
rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
subprojects {
project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
}
subprojects {
project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
}
tasks.register("clean", Delete) {
delete rootProject.buildDir
}


app level:
plugins {
    id "com.android.application"
    // START: FlutterFire Configuration
    id 'com.google.gms.google-services'
    // END: FlutterFire Configuration
    id "kotlin-android"
    id "dev.flutter.flutter-gradle-plugin"
}

def localProperties = new Properties()
def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
    localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
        localProperties.load(reader)
    }
}

def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionCode')
if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
    flutterVersionCode = '1'
}

def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionName')
if (flutterVersionName == null) {
    flutterVersionName = '1.0'
}

android {
    namespace "com.example.devproj"
    compileSdk flutter.compileSdkVersion
    ndkVersion flutter.ndkVersion

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }

    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId "com.example.devproj"
        // You can update the following values to match your application needs.
        // For more information, see: https://docs.flutter.dev/deployment/android#reviewing-the-gradle-build-configuration.
        minSdkVersion 23
        targetSdkVersion flutter.targetSdkVersion
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            // TODO: Add your own signing config for the release build.
            // Signing with the debug keys for now, so `flutter run --release` works.
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
    }
}

flutter {
    source '../..'
}

dependencies {}



Run ./gradlew signingReportit will show your SHA1
Paste your SHA1 key on firebase console then
Download and replace the google-services.json
then run flutter clean

Hi, when i run that i get this:
Starting a Gradle Daemon, 1 busy Daemon could not be reused, use --status for details

Task :gradle:compileGroovy FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':gradle:compileGroovy'.


BUG! exception in phase 'semantic analysis' in source unit 'C:\Users\DELL\Desktop\flutter\flutter\packages\flutter_tools\gradle\src\main\groovy\app_plugin_loader.groovy' Unsupported class file major version 65


As it is the Groovy compilation that is failing, I guess you are using a Groovy version that is not Java 21 compatible. Can you post project level gradle file?

allprojects {
repositories {
google()
mavenCentral()
}
}
rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
subprojects {
project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
}
subprojects {
project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
}
tasks.register("clean", Delete) {
delete rootProject.buildDir
}

Edit your question and post there

I have edited and added the project level build.gradle file

downgrade jdk version 21 to 17 then it will work

would i  need to delete my older jdk version or just set my environment variable to the newer one?

Its depends which os you are using like Mac or Windows. Just google it
